# Boxplot on conditioned data in a dataframe

Tags: r, boxplot

I am new to R, can anyone help me with boxplot for a dataset like:

file1

```
     col1 col2     col3     col4  col5
050350005  101   56.625   48.318 RED    
051010002  106   50.625   46.990 GREEN    
051190007   25   65.875   74.545 BLUE    
051191002  246   52.875   57.070 RED    
220050004   55   70       80.274 BLUE    
220150008   75   67.750   62.749 RED    
220170001   77   65.750   54.307 GREEN
```

file2

```
     col1 col2     col3     col4  col5
050350005  101   56.625   57     RED
051010002  106   50.625   77     GREEN    
051190007   25   65.875   51.6   BLUE    
051191002  246   52.875   55.070 RED    
220050004   55   70       32     BLUE    
220150008   75   67.750   32.49  RED
220170001   77   65.750   84.07  GREEN
```

for each color (red,green and blue), I need to compare file1 and file2 by making box plot with MB and RMSE for (`col4`-`col3`) for file1 and file2 by dividing `col2` in different group:

if col2<20,20<=col2<50, 50 <= col2 <70, col2 >=70.

That is, for the boxplot, the x is (<20, 20-50,50-70, >70), while y is MB (and RMSE) of the difference of `col4` and `col3`

I hope I didn't confuse anybody. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a bit of confusion about what a boxplot does/is. While it is possible to create groups on the x axis, as far as I know, the y axis shows the distribution of a certain measure (I assume either col3 or col4, in your case), not the RMSE or MBE of those measurements, which would be a single value for each group.

I am not sure if your grouping variable (for the x axis) is col5, the files or the criteria you list for col2, or all of them? Regardless, you would need more data for the plots to be meaningful.

This is a basic example of a boxplot of col3 grouped by col5 and file:

```
col3 = c(56.625, 50.625, 65.875, 52.875, 70, 67.750, 65.750, 56.625, 50.625, 65.875, 52.875, 70, 67.750, 65.750)
col5 = c("RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "RED", "BLUE", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE","RED","BLUE","RED","GREEN")
myfile = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
mydata = data.frame(col3, col5, myfile)
boxplot(col3 ~ col5 + myfile, data = mydata)
```

Note that because the number of cases is limited, you do not see the whiskers on some categories, nor the outliers. You would need more data for this plot to be useful, right now all it is showing is a comparison of medians.

Can you clarify what you were hoping the plot would show?